# how to handle old questions out of date answers

Tags: discussion

there are many questions and answers that I encounter are wrong or missleading for newbie because out of date .

ill give one example for the [question, uploading photo with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770122/android-upload-image-from-gallery-to-server). the link of those tutorials are not good because old (and  I guess they will not work now because they are not using `Asynctask`  ).

its not about one or two questions they are several . newbies will spend time on them thinking they are okay because accepted answer but they are not.

edit : 
A question was posted about a year addressing the problem and still misleading questions exists in SO.

Comment: Downvote, comment, stop worrying. Move on.

Comment: @rene then question was answered from a year and still there misleading questions or wrong. I don't care if you (as the coumunity )don't want to do anything about it. I am just pointing about a problem.

Comment: @Moudiz are you saying the duplicate is wrong? If so, how? You're as much part of the community as I am....

Comment: @rene the dup question  its wrong because they didnt fix the issue. still missleading or wrong questions exists.

Comment: @IKavanagh this will not solve the issue , I am worring because I tried a question in so and it was wrong . something annoying

Comment: @Moudiz I understand but what else can you do, except for that or writing your own answer? Flagging is incorrect.

Comment: @Moudiz I have downvoted the question and the accepted answer and voted to close the question. I'll cast a delete vote  2 days after it has been closed.

Comment: Yes ill guess ill write a new answer addressing that its an old way

Answer (score 1):

When I arrived at that question it didn't had any down votes nor had the accepted answer.

Looking at the question it had no code and no visible attempt. I therefor casted a close vote as too broad and down voted the question and the answers.

You seem to be worried about the many questions and answers in this state and came to meta to seek help. You can always use your own votes and flags on posts you see that have an issue. Use comments to inform both OP's and other visitors what issue arise from the post.

This site is after all community moderated and you are, just like me, part of that community. Don't expect others to do the heavy lifting, we need every ones vote to keep the posts up to date and valuable.